# Is there a way to improve on git's default chunking behaviour?

Tags: git

It happens quite frequently to me that git will decide that the changes I made are all one big complicated chunk in the diff instead of 2+ simpler chunks (say an edit and an insertion after that).

Does git have any options for changing how it decides which changes go together in chunks?

Comment: You might want to see if a non-default algorithm already built into git helps (mainly see if `--diff-algorithm=patience` helps): `--diff-algorithm={patience|minimal|histogram|myers}`

Comment: Awesome, that works great. If you make it an answer I'll pick it.